# objective c post image and form data

Tags: php, objective-c, post

Hi im trying to upload from my iphone app an image and few textfelds of data to a PHP script on my web server.  Ive found some code on the net to upload an image and i have added a small bit which i thought might upload two text fields with the data.  My image is uploading fine but i do not seem to be getting my textfileds across.  When i echo it from my php script it is showing blank.  I don't think its my php script at fault as all i am simply doing is 
$item1 = $_POST ['item1'];
echo $item1

is my objective c code i am using below look right?

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text1\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[text1.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text2\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[text2.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust

[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:connectionURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```